# Launch two android applications from 1 apk file

Tags: android

I need to create an android application that launches a new application. the new application need to run on a different process from the orig app, need to have a different package name, it needs to be graphic (so I think that rules out services, unless I'm mistaken and services can be graphic) and it needs to be installed with the same apk file as the first. 
it won't get to android market, so I don't care about market issues.

I saw today an application that do exactly what I need, It ran on a process under it's package name, and opened up a new process under "{orig.app.packgename}:remote".

anyone can tell me how can something like that can be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As stated above, a single APK can only accommodate one app.

You can always suggest to your user installation of another app, but I
understand this is not what you want here.

So, here's a small trick that will deliver most of what you aim for
(accept for different package names, no way to do this) wrapped within
a single APK:

First:  Add a android:process tag to your stand-alone activity:

```
<activity android:name=".StandAloneActivity" 
     android:process=":MyNewProcess">
```

This will inform Android that this activity **should be executed on a separate process**
whose name is "MyNewProcess". You can add additional components (Activities, Services..) labelled as ":MyNewProcess". They will all be executed on the same process.

Then: Create an "action.MAIN" intent filter for BOTH your stand-alone activity
and your app's main activity:

```
<activity  android:name=".MainActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


<activity
    android:name=".StandAloneActivity"
    android:process=":MyNewProcess" >
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

This will inform Android that **two distinct homescreen icons** needs to be created for your app, one for each of the MAIN activities (now running on separate processes).

Needless to say, standard method invocations will not pass through from one
process to another. You will need to use [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), [AIDL interfaces](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) or whichever
other IPC mechanism your little heart desires

Comment: this is almost exactly what I wanted. in the hacky way I use to find the package names of running packages, I even got the different package name I wanted, that was {my.package.name}:MyNewProcess. 
I say almost because I deleted the second intent filter in order to prevent the second activity to get a Launcher Icon of it's own.

Answer (score 3):

Each application must have it's own apk file, and each application can only have one package name. The solution is two have the other application apk in your resource files and install it in run time, or if it's already installed, just launch it.

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is Intents (probably that's what you mean). Many applications register some of their Activities to be launched from different applications. For example when you click reply to an e-mail the "reply" activity of an email application you might have installed is launched (for example Gmail). Bear in mind that "an application that launches another application" poses some security risks so some requirements for that kind of actions must be met.

Answer (score 0):

Ilya is right, you need to either install them separately or include the other apk in your resources and install it when the app is ran for the first time.

Then you can simply use an intent to start the app.